# Loading table and data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, linear-regression

everyone. I am new in R, so I need help. :) I copied some columns from one table (ulpod) to another (ulpod1), and I have a problem with column made of string. They are being displayed as number instead of string. For example, you can see the Country UK is displayed as numbers 18. Here is code example and result:

```
    ulpod<-read.xlsx("C:/Users/milica/Desktop/VESNAseminarski/AE&DE.xls",sheetIndex=1,sheetName="Sheet1",startRow=1,endRow=955,colIndex=c(1:14,1),header=TRUE)
     options(max.print=2000000000)

     ulpod1=matrix(0,90,12)
     m=1

     ulpod1='colnames<-'(ulpod1,c("Year","Country","CO2_pc","Fertilizer","AgrLand","Forest","CropIndex","FoodIndex","LivestIndex","RuralPopGrow","AVA","GDP_pc"))

    for(i in 1:954){
      if(ulpod[i,1]=="1990" || ulpod[i,1]=="2000" || ulpod[i,1]=="2005" || ulpod[i,1]=="2008" || ulpod[i,1]=="2010"){
        ulpod1[m,1]=ulpod[i,1];
        ulpod1[m,2]=ulpod[i,2];
        ulpod1[m,3]=ulpod[i,3];
        ulpod1[m,4]=ulpod[i,4];
        ulpod1[m,5]=ulpod[i,5];
        ulpod1[m,6]=ulpod[i,6];
        ulpod1[m,7]=ulpod[i,7];
        ulpod1[m,8]=ulpod[i,8];
        ulpod1[m,9]=ulpod[i,9];
        ulpod1[m,10]=ulpod[i,10];
        ulpod1[m,11]=ulpod[i,11];
        ulpod1[m,12]=ulpod[i,14];
        m=m+1;
        i=i+1;
        }

    Year=ulpod1[,1,drop=FALSE]
    Country=ulpod1[,2,drop=FALSE]
    CO2_pc=ulpod1[,3,drop=FALSE]
    Fertilizer=ulpod1[,4,drop=FALSE]
    AgrLand=ulpod1[,5,drop=FALSE]
    Forest=ulpod1[,6,drop=FALSE]
    CropIndex=ulpod1[,7,drop=FALSE]
    FoodIndex=ulpod1[,8,drop=FALSE]
    LivestIndex=ulpod1[,9,drop=FALSE]
    RuralPopGrow=ulpod1[,10,drop=FALSE]
    AVA=ulpod1[,11,drop=FALSE]
    GDP_pc=ulpod1[,12,drop=FALSE]
```

The result I get when call head(Country,10) is:

```
    Country
     [1,]       9
     [2,]       9
     [3,]       9
     [4,]       9
     [5,]       9
     [6,]      18
     [7,]      18
     [8,]      18
     [9,]      18
     [10,]      18
```

Because of this I have a problem with data frame:

```
    P<-pdata.frame(ulpod1,index=c("Year","Country"))
```

the error is:

```
    Error in x[, !na.check] : (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think you're doing this `m <- matrix(0); m[1,1] <- factor('a'); m` so you could change your factors to characters `m <- matrix(0); m[1,1] <- as.character(factor('a')); m`

Comment: I did this already, I changed the line ulpod1[m,2]=ulpod[i,2] with ulpod1[m,2]=as.character(factor(ulpod[i,2]));  or ulpod1[m,2]=as.character(ulpod[i,2]); in for loop, but the I get all columns as strings. See results below:  @rawr

Comment: Year   Country          CO2_pc               
         [1,] "1990" "Ireland"        "-0.220554400992975" 
         [2,] "2000" "Ireland"        "-0.127178700493732" 
         [3,] "2005" "Ireland"        "-0.144987627991366" 
         [4,] "2008" "Ireland"        "-0.187046990811592" 
         [5,] "2010" "Ireland"        "-0.229643587654196" 
         [6,] "1990" "United Kingdom" "-0.167837810150395"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If strings are displayed as numbers, that is a shure sign, that they have been read in as factors instead of characters. The right place to change that would be when reading in, i. e. in read.xlsx() with StringsAsFactors=FALSE as an argument.

In the comments you mention, that when you change one column with as.character, than all columns become strings. The reason is, that you store your data in a matrix. All elements of a matrix are of the same type. You should probably store your data (ulpod1) in a data.frame instead of a matrix. Each column in a data.frame can have a different type.

```
> m <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),nrow=3)
> str(m)
 num [1:3, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> m[1,2]<-as.character(m[1,2])
> str(m)
 chr [1:3, 1:3] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
```

Comment: I stored like ulpod1=data.frame(ulpod1) and now works, thank you. But now, when I call:                                                                                                                  P<-pdata.frame(ulpod1,index=c("Year","Country"),row.names = TRUE); rez=plm(CO2_pc~Fertilizer+AgrLand+Forest+CropIndex+LivestIndex+RuralPopGrow+AVA+GDP_pc,data=P)  , there is a error:   Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ X - 1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'X')....why? In my opinion this is okay, all of these columns have dimension 90x1

Comment: This second question is really hard to answer without seeing the data. A data.frame called P was not mentioned before. Check `str(P)` for possible reasons or post a new question including the output of  `str(P)`

Comment: plm function for linear regression requires pdata.frames...the syntax is plm(formula=Y~X, pdata.frame,...). There is no problem with P, I think... Thanks anaway...:)